# Need apple Mac developer account for distribute free app?

Tags: macos, app-store, account

I'm developing Mac app for free.
In iOS , we need developer account to distribute for upload into iTunes Store.
In Mac application, Is that also need to mac developer account for free distribute.
Firefox distribute their app free , we can download that dmg file from their website , not in Mac app store.

Please let me know is that need?

Comment: If you want to distribute you application using the AppStore, you need a developer account, even if your app will be free

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a developer account to submit your application to any of Apple's online stores. The price you want to sell for is irrelevant (even if that price is $0).

You don't need one to distribute the program yourself.

---

iOS will not allow software to be installed except with the Apple online store. The exceptions are:

- Web applications
- Jailbroken iOS devices

OS X Lion and earlier has no restrictions on what software can be installed.

OS X Mountain Lion will have a user preference that can limit software install sources (including the strictest setting which limits it to the Apple App Store only).

Comment: So you mean , for Lion , i don't need dev account .
But for Mountain lion , i need dev account for distribute even free?

Comment: No. You only need that for systems which have been configured to restrict software installs to the App Store.